# Beggining in Algebraic Geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, book-recommendation

My question is about sources for start the study of algebraic geometry. I know that it requieres so much algebra, but, is there any book which can be readed without many tolos of modules, Galois, etc?, or any source i can find in this área contains a lot of things that lies in the algebra field?

Thanks.

Comment: "I know that it requieres so much algebra" is not necessarily true.  Two texts that start (I believe) with minimal algebraic prerequisites are _Elementary Algebraic Geometry_ by Hulek, and _Undergraduate Algebraic Geometry_ by Reid. OTher questions on this site provide more suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

This question is already asked here...

An Invitation to Algebraic Geometry http://books.google.co.in/books/about/An_Invitation_to_Algebraic_Geometry.html?id=itU48VQYJwwC would be better for first reading....

Elementary Algebraic Geometry  [http://www.amazon.com/Elementary-Algebraic-Geometry-Student-Mathematical/dp/0821829521](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821829521) would be another useful book for beginners